# Como resumir esse código em uma list comprehension?

Tags: python

Estou praticando para fazer tudo que for possível em 'comprehension', alguém saberia uma forma de fazer isso com este código:

```
letras = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

vogais = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

total = 0

for x in letras:
  if x in consoantes:
    total += 1
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow. No [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp), eles explicam sobre esse List Comprehension. Não entendi o que fazer com o total, mas acredito que o você realmente quer é ```list = [x for x in letras if x in consoantes]```. Retornando assim todas as vogais (não consoantes) da lista Letras.

Comment: Eu acho que nesse caso list comprehension não é a melhor opção. A ideia da list comprehension é criar uma lista, mas vc só quer a quantidade, então criar uma lista só para pegar o tamanho me parece um exagero. Para listas pequenas, esse `for` que vc fez é mais que suficiente. **Se** as listas forem muito grandes, talvez valha a pena usar `set`, por exemplo, `total = len(set(letras) & set(consoantes))` ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/79BwC9) como faz diferença - lembrando que só vale a pena se as listas forem muito grandes, mas para o seu caso, esse loop que vc fez é o bastante)

Comment: De resto, prefira sempre a documentação oficial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions - w3schools não é lá essas coisas (já foi pior, melhorou um pouco, mas a documentação oficial do Python é muito boa)

Comment: Agradeço os esclarecimentos, realmente é exagero sim, admito. Mas é apenas para acostumar com list comprehension, mais uma questão de aprender a lidar com ela. Realmente errei no nome da lista, vou corrigi RS. Essa questão de ser necessário ou não, ser mais um exagero ou o mais objetivo possível, ainda estou tentando me acostumar e melhorar. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

**Criando uma lista com as vogais**

Como comentaram, para você obter a lista de vogais da sua lista inicial utilizando *list comprehension*, você poderia fazer:

```py
letras = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
vogais = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

resultado = [letra for letra in letras if letra in vogais]
# ['a', 'e', 'i']
```

Perceba que aqui também chamei a variável de controle de `letra` ao invés de `x` para deixar ainda mais intuitivo o código.

Com isso você pode fazer `len(resultado)` para calcular a quantidade de vogais na lista, mas também como comentado, isso só fará sentido se você precisar acessar essa lista, pois se precisar apenas saber a quantidade, não precisa criar a lista `resultado`.

**Solução utilizando conjuntos**

Também foi sugerido nos comentários em utilizar o `set`, que é a forma como o Python lida com conjuntos. A sugestão foi converter as duas listas em conjuntos e validar a intersecção entre elas:

```py
total = len(set(letras) & set(vogais))
```

Isso funciona, porém limitado a situações em que você possui letras distintas - ou se deseja validar se existe quaisquer vogais na lista, sem importar a quantidade de cada uma. Isso ocorre porque ao gerar um conjunto a partir da sua lista as múltiplas ocorrências de um mesmo valor serão tratados como uma só, removendo a redundância.

Assim, se você possuir uma lista tal qual `letras = ['a', 'a', 'a']` o valor de `total` seria 1, indicando que há uma vogal, por considerar que as três ocorrências da letra `'a'` são iguais. Se isso não for um problema para você, é uma solução válida. Se precisar contar quantas ocorrências há mesmo quando há redundância, a solução com conjuntos não se aplica.

Como comentado, verifique sempre o tamanho da sua lista antes de aplicar essa solução. O custo de se criar um conjunto para validar a quantidade das ocorrências pode invalidar a solução.

**Calculando ocorrências sem novas listas e considerando redundância**

Uma forma de você calcular a quantidade de ocorrências de vogais na sua lista considerando as possíveis redundâncias, sem criar uma nova lista e sem muito custo operacional é utilizando geradores. Com Python, você pode criar um gerador com a sintaxe da *list comprehension*, porém sem os colchetes. Isso fará com que a lista seja percorrida sempre com apenas um elemento em memória, o que é ótimo caso a sua lista cresça demasiadamente - e faz com que, nessa parte, a solução seja O(1), independente do tamanho da sua lista.

```py
total = sum(1 for letra in letras if letra in vogais)
```

Ou, se você lembrar que em Python o tipo booleano é um sub-tipo do `int`, em que `True` é avaliado como 1 e `False` como 0, você poderia fazer:

```py
total = sum(letra in vogais for letra in letras)
```

Gerando o mesmo resultado, embora para mim já não fica tão intuitivo. Eu prefiro a primeira versão.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos!